# Application gets crashed due to null pointer exception after the android version is upgraded(Android 11 to Android 12)

Tags: java, android

Invisible function from the holder does not work, stating that the relevant ImageView is NULL. This works perfectly fine on Android 11 but as soon as upgraded to Android 12 , the above error occurs and app gets crashed.

```
class eqViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView eqNameTV, modNumTV, prtNumTV, serNumTV, expireDateTV, indicator, expiresOnTV, STCTV;
    AppCompatButton editBtn,deleteBtn;
    
    //Declaration of relevant ImageView
    ImageView expiredImage;
    
    
    CardView itemCard;
    String exactMonth;
    String exactDay;
    String year, color;

    public eqViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        eqNameTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.equipNameTV);
        modNumTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelNumTV);
        prtNumTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.partNumTV);
        serNumTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.serialNumTV);
        expiresOnTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expires_onTV);
        expireDateTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expireDateTV);
        editBtn = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        deleteBtn = (AppCompatButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        indicator = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        itemCard = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCardView);
        
        //Initialization of relevant ImageView
        expiredImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.expiredImage);
        
        STCTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.STCCheckBox);

        System.out.println(expiredImage);

    }
}
```

[Error shown when the app is crashing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpX2g.png)

```
//line 125
holder.expiredImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right ID (expiredImage)? Can you show us the layout file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the correct ID and this application works perfectly on Android 11 or below

Comment: This is the code in the layout file  ` <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expiredImage"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/indicator"
            android:layout_marginStart="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:rotation="-30"
            android:src="@drawable/expired2" />`